# Should I make bus reservations in Mexico in early spring?

Tags: transportation, mexico

I'm currently staying in CDMX. I'm planning to have a day trip to Teotihuacan Mar. 28th. In additional, I'm also going to Oaxaca City the day after (Mar. 29th).

I've heard from various sources that the buses get very busy during the Easter week, so should I make reservations online now? I checked the ADO website, and it seems that the buses for this week are still pretty empty. I'm trying my best not to make any reservations because I don't like having my itinerary restricted by some fixed transportation schedule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was in a similar situation on Christmas Eve in Oaxaca, so can't be sure it applies 1:1 but I'd suspect that it's similar? I was convinced that the buses would be sold out. Turns out, there are many less formal bus companies competing with ADO on the major routes - it was easy enough to get a seat on one of those or even with ADO. You run the risk of the best seats or the exact times being sold out but it seems there is a lot of capacity in general at peak times and you're like to get from A to B.

ADO's advanced purchases price were cheaper though.